# Selenium Python, Find element Input box problems

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to automate some processes at work on our inventory site and I'm having trouble inputing text into a simple search box!

Here is the website code:

```
<td class="GJCH5BMASD" style=""> 
 <input type="text" class="GJCH5BMD1C GJCH5BME1C" style="font-size: 13px;      width: 100%;">
</td>
```

Here is my code:

```
opens = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".GJCH5BMD1C GJCH5BME1C").click()
```

I keep receiving the error:

```
ElementNotVisibleException: Cannot click on element
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: oops the web code didnt post

Comment: <td class="GJCH5BMASD" style=""> <input type="text" class="GJCH5BMD1C GJCH5BME1C" style="font-size: 13px; width: 100%;"> </td><input type="text" class="GJCH5BMD1C GJCH5BME1C" style="font-size: 13px; width: 100%;">

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please go through the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) and the [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) sections to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions, which can help you get better answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well nevermind!

I fixed it by changing:

```
opens = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".GJCH5BMD1C GJCH5BME1C").click()
```

to:

```
opens = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".GJCH5BMASD").click()
```

Comment: Please don't forget to come back and mark the question as answered.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide `.` with every class name using `css_selector`, you can also try as below :-

```
opens = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".GJCH5BMD1C.GJCH5BME1C").click()
```